# Pygame not detecting duplicate keyboard input events

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi

We're building a hardware device using a raspberry pi with a barcode scanner and a display. The barcode scanner functions like a USB keyboard, and sends keystrokes in quick succession after scanning a barcode. We're having a problem with pygame not detecting duplicate keys from the scanner in quick succession. When running the below code, pygame often misses duplicate keys. Example output from scanning the same barcode:

```
5770857738
5770857738
570857738
577085738
57085738
5770857738
577085738
5770857738
5770857738
5770857738
5770857738
577085738
5770857738
570857738
5770857738
```

If I comment out the last three lines however (not updating the screen), the code is scanned successfully every time.

We're using pygame 2.1.2 with python 3.9.2 on a raspberry pi.

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))
ID = ""
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 70)
while True:
    text = font.render("testtext", True, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0))
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.center = (screen.get_width() // 2, screen.get_height() // 2)
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            key = pygame.key.name(event.key)
            if key.isdigit():
                ID += key
            elif key == "return":
                print(ID)
                ID = ""
            elif key == "left":
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text, textRect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

From testing it looks like there is about 3-4 miliseconds between each keystroke being sent by the scanner.

We've tried detecting keystrokes in a separate thread with different libraries, but have so far not found a workable solution.

Comment: It seems to be a hardware problem, but not a problem with the software.

Comment: As mentioned it works when I comment out the code that updates the screen so I don't think it's a hardware problem.

Comment: So it is a bug in Pygame and not a question that can be answered. Create an issue: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues

Comment: You should have something that notices when a barcode is being scanned, and then decates the program the program to reading input only.

Comment: Is this question in some way specific to python 3? If not, please replace the python-3.x tag with the python tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your main loop is notorious for not adding *any* delay between screen frame updates - this will make the screen updtae use 100% CPU - and it is likely the event engine is doing the equivalent of "frame skiping" when it finally has a chance to run.

Just add a `pygame.time.delay(30)` (pause 30 miliseconds) after the call to `.display.flip()` - that should give your O.S. a breath to catch up with the events. Since you said that commenting out any screen updates, it works, I am confident that given this  space you should be fine.

Comment: It's better to use a `pygame.time.Clock()` object and call its [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) method with the desired frame rate.

Answer (score 0):

> If I comment out the last three lines however (not updating the screen), the code is scanned successfully every time.

I would use an if statement to temporarily "comment out" these lines when input from the barcode scanner is received:

```py
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))
ID = ""
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 70)
scanning = False
while True:
    text = font.render("testtext", True, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0))
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.center = (screen.get_width() // 2, screen.get_height() // 2)
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            key = pygame.key.name(event.key)
            if key.isdigit():
                scanning = True
                ID += key
            elif key == "return":
                scanning = False
                print(ID)
                ID = ""
            elif key == "left":
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
    if not scanning:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(text, textRect)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

As I don't have a barcode scanner, I'm unable to test this code. I have tested using keyboard input, but I have no idea of the time delay between my different keystrokes. All my tests were passed correctly

Answer (score 0):

As you and others have identified, the relentless screen updates are pegging your CPU causing missed events. The idiomatic way to handle this in pygame is though a [`pygame.time.Clock()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object.

So you could create a clock before your main loop:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    ...
```

and then after your display update, call `clock.tick()` to limit the frame rate

```
pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(60)  # limit to 60 FPS
```

For me this changes the CPU utilisation from 25% (maxing one of four cores) to 1%. You're also recreating the text every loop which is not necessary, although I expect it's a place holder for future dynamic text.

Here's a slightly reworked version of your code with a `Clock()` and using pygame constants where possible:

```
import sys
import string
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))
ID = ""
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 70)
text = font.render("testtext", True, "white", "black")
text_rect = text.get_rect()
text_rect.center = (screen.get_width() // 2, screen.get_height() // 2)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.unicode and event.unicode in string.digits:
                ID += event.unicode
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                print(ID)
                ID = ""
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                running = False
    screen.fill("black")
    screen.blit(text, text_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```